# Zend Framework 2 - DI and having to inject table adapter into tables... tedious?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I just read the Rob Allen's akrabat ZF2 tutorial (http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf) on how to inject dependencies into your stuff like, injecting in your table adapter into your table classes.

This seems to be how I'm supposed to do it:

```
        array(
            'Application\Model\DbTable\UserTable',
        ) => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
            )
        ),

        array(
            'Application\Model\DbTable\UserProfileTable',
        ) => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
            )
        ),
```

Ok that's pretty cool but I've got around 84 tables so am I going to have to add each of these and say that I want PdoMySQL injecting into them all. Is there any proper way to do this such as specifying my entire DbTable folder? Not even this works:

```
        array(
            'Application\Model\DbTable\UserTable',
            'Application\Model\DbTable\UserProfileTable'
        ) => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
            )
        ),
```

Anyone else doing this and found a better solution?

Thanks, Dom

Comment: Just looking at where you define the arrays (and use arrays for keys), I was under the impression that array keys could only be strings or integers in PHP. Can someone correct me if this is wrong?

Comment: Yeah makes sense :D I tried looking at injecting the DB Adapter directly into AbstractTable but its an abstract class and that doesn't work. I then tried putting it into Zend\Db\Table\Table and then extend this but again that doesn't work... There has to be a better way around this than specifying the same code 90 times

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a good one, and I agree, this a scenario where dependency injection does NOT make sense. I haven't browsed the ZF2 API yet, did they completely abandon the ability to bind adapter at the connection level, rather than the table level?

In my database class I use a yaml file to store connection settings; username, password, adapter, etc. I did it in a format which can be passed straight to Zend_Config, which can then be passed to the Zend_Db class.

```
// Entry in connection.yml
database:
  adapter: Pdo_Mysql
  params:
    host:     myhost
    dbname:   mydatabase
    username: myusername
    password: mypassword

// Parse yaml file to get above snippet in an array ($dbConnectionparams)

$config = new Zend_Config($dbConnectionParams);

$dbo = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
```

Now, If I ever need to change the adapter for a database connection I only need to change it in one location, the connection.yml file.

Also, I believe you can store this type of connection data in various other formats (xml, etc).

Comment: I think I may have stumbled upon the answer! It looks like EvanDotPro has created a class `DiPdoMysql` which looks like an extension of PdoMysql for friendly Di. https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpUser
The DiPdoMysql is in https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpCommon/tree/master/src/Zend/Db/Adapter

Comment: @DominicWatson: Interesting, seems like ZF2 should supoort this type of behavior natively.

Comment: Aye, I think I remember reading that his DiPdoMysql class was there until Zend\DB was fully rewritten :D

Comment: I guess the above is slightly different with ZF2 now being released. The above was something like Beta 1. Same still applies... I've got 84 tables to copy, paste and inject the adapter into. My ServiceManager file is going to be needlessly huuuge

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAwareInterface in your model classes and request them via service manager in your controllers. Take a look at my blog post for more details: http://cmyker.blogspot.com/2012/11/zend-framework-2-model-database-adapter.html